# aggregation with filter on powerbi

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, dax, powerbi-desktop

i have several sums that i want to aggregate but i'm not enought confortable with dax to do so :

[image]

I want to aggregate 16500 + 8979 +16604 + 18347 to remplace "156084" by the result.

The point is, for every result, i didnt do a Dax function but i used te Powerbi filters options that it can not be used to agreggate numbers :

[image]

I want to have the sum of the `Nb de logements` filtered by 'date promesse de ventes réelles' without nulls cells.

I think i have to use Filter or Related Dax function, but i don't know how to settle it.

I tried this:

```
    Logements par promesse réelle = 'Opérations'[Nb de logements]
FILTER(IF(NOT(ISBLANK'Dates réelles'[date promesse de vente réelles])
```

But the formul isnt working and i'm not able to fix it

I also tried this:

```
 Logements par promesse réelle = 
CALCULATE(
 'Opérations'[Nb de logements],
FILTER('Dates réelles'[date promesse de vente réelles],NOT(ISBLANK)))
```

but i have this error message:
[image]

which means: "

```
It is not possible to determine a unique value for the column "date promesse de vente réelles" of the "Dates réelles" table. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values, without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.
```

Thank you for reading it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to return the SUM for 'Opérations'[Nb de logements] for all dates that are not blank. In that case, I'd write the DAX like this:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Opérations'[Nb de logements]),
    NOT(ISBLANK('Dates réelles'[date promesse de vente réelles]))
)
```

Does this solve your issue?